# How to get/set default image scanner in windows powershell (WIA)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, scanner

I am trying to build a program that involves scanning. I am trying to use powershell to just scan a document and save it to a specified location, and I have found a program that I can use through powershell called wia-cmd-scanner.exe, which has been super helpful for solving this, but it seems to just use the default scanner, and I'd like to be able to specify which scanner to use. I am not very familiar with powershell as I usually use linux, so how can I get and set the default scanner in windows 10 powershell?  In practice, these will probably be usb attached scanners, if it matters.

Edit: l am working with WIA scanners, like document scanners

Comment: There is no such thing as a *system default scanner*.

Comment: Maybe the word system was misleading. But when l google how to set the default scanner, l do get results, just not from a command line. And there is a default printer, so why not a default scanner?

Comment: I remember scanners. They still live? So not a radar scanner. Perhaps edit your question to make clear you are talking about hardware scanners as many other things use the term.

Comment: I've updated it, sorry for any confusion.